# How to express the set builder notation of these properties?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

1. Set $A$ where elements are the leap year from year $1900$ to $1930$.
2. $E$ is a set $\{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,\dots,1024\}$ where $x$ is computed as $x = 2^n$ and $n$ has a maximum value of $10$.

My answers are:

1. $A=\left\{x\mid1900< x <1930\land\text{$x$ is incremented by four}\right\}$
2. I don't know how to answer this one.

Comment: Incremented by four starting from what?  How is it determined if a year is a leap year?

Comment: I'm sorry but is my answer wrong, would you please help me answer it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $E = \{2^{n} \in \mathbb{N}| 0\leq n \leq 10 \}$

Answer (score 0):

- $E = \{2^{n} \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}| 0\leq n \leq 10 \}$

Comment: Quick tip: You can use `\mid` instead of `|` (it looks better).